# cannot add a directory containing git cloned subdiretories?

Tags: git, clone, addition

I have a `directoryA` which contains sub directories which I created via `git clone`

I want to create a git repository for the `directoryA`.
But when I do `git add -A && git commit -m "w"` nothing gets committed.

Do I need to take a special care for dealing with `git-cloned subdirectories`?

`directoryA` is my special directory for collection of libraries I use for my project.

Comment: I think you want to look at git submodules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are creating are uninitialized submodules, and yes submodules require a bit of special handling to use them effectively.

Once the submodule is initialized, you will be able to commit the sub directory it lives in from the parent project.

Submodules go beyond basic git with a bit more of a learning curve, but once understood serve their purpose well and merge nicely with the rest of git.

What makes the handling of submodules special can be summed up in a few key concepts:

- Submodules must be initialized before the parent repository knows about them.
- Submodules must be cloned, updated and commited specifically, although there are command options that automate some of this.
- Submodules are full repositories with a single commit checked out; as such they are headless and a branch must be created before any changes made can be commited.
- Any changes to submodules should be checked in first, before the changes to the parent repository.  The parent update of the submodule is actually an updating of which of the submodules commits the parent knows about.

Here are a few links that were very helpful to me when I had the need to take the plunge into submodules, which has been quite helpful in keeping track of the various pieces of my projects.

> [Git Tools - SubModules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)
>
> [Git Submodules:  Adding, Using, Removing, Updating](http://chrisjean.com/2009/04/20/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/)
>
> [Understanding Git Submodules](http://speirs.org/blog/2009/5/11/understanding-git-submodules.html)

Answer (score 0):

In general, `git` does not allow to have one git repository to be in sub-directory of another.

The only exception to this rule is to use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). However, this has a lot of other implications which you may not like. For example, parent git repository must track at which particular commit id submodule must be checked out. If you commit new stuff into submodule - locally or pull it from outside, you must also change parent repo state and create one more commit to reflect submodule state.

To solve these issues, Android project has created another way to deal with these issues, namely they created [`repo`](http://source.android.com/source/version-control.html). While `repo` is used mostly by Android projects, it is very generic mechanism that can be used for any other purpose.

`repo` relies on XML file called manifest (it lives in small git repository of its own). Manifest defines where all git repositories that define the whole project are checked out and at what revisions and branches. It is very powerful mechanism. The only limitation of repo is that it does not support Windows because it requires to use symbolic links (but Linux and Mac are supported very well).

Comment: `directoryA` is my special directory for collection of libraries I use for my project.  Should I look at submodules?

Comment: you can also use android `repo` - I think you will have more trouble with submodules in the long run (I have updated my answer to describe `repo`)